# Error in a bash script that doesn't write the cout and cerr output on files

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script for pick the cout and cerr output of 2 different programs in differents files. But it doesn't work! 
For run the following code you must have in /home/user/Scrivania/ the 2 binary files: myLearning0 and myLearning1. Actually even without the eval the code is executed (and for execute the next binary file you wait the end of the current running binary file) but the files in the folder are not created and written(even if they already exists) . Is this a permission problem, or what else?

```
bin_dir="/home/user/Scrivania/"
base_name_exe="./myLearning"
base_path_risultati="/home/user/Scrivania/Risultati/"
file1_name_base="${base_path_risultati}results"
file2_name_base="${base_path_risultati}shortresults"

cd $bin_dir
for i in $(seq 0 1)
do
  file1_name=$file1_name_base$i
  file2_name=$file2_name_base$i
  name_exe=$base_name_exe$i
  #echo $file1_name
  #echo $file2_name
  #echo $name_exe
  command="${name_exe} > ${file1_name}.txt 2> ${file2_name}.txt"
  echo $command
  $command
done

exit
```

(The binary files are created from C++ source code, and I'm on Unix system)

Comment: This is [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). (Frankly, you'll get a better answer from that FAQ than from the linked question).

Comment: ...you might also want to run your code through http://shellcheck.net/, and fix what it finds.

Comment: (BTW, why `for i in $(seq 0 1); do`, rather than `for i in 0 1; do`? If you want a larger range, the better way to do it is not with `seq` (a nonstandard command that isn't actually included in bash) but with a [C-style `for` loop](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/c_for): `for ((i=0; i<=1; i++))`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm not interested in perfect code, it's enough that it works

Comment: That's a dangerous position to take, particularly in shell, where sloppy code can have unexpected side effects when handling unusual data. I've seen TBs of billing data backups destroyed by code that "worked" -- until a bug in a separate program that generated a filename with random data in the same directory that contained a whitespace-surrounded wildcard; that "working" script tried to delete the file, and deleted everything else in the same store.

Comment: I've also seen "working" scripts responsible for shell injection vulnerabilities (ie. `eval "grep -e $input /var/log/*.log"`, letting an attacker put `$(rm -rf ~)` (or anything else they want) in the variable that's substituted into `input`. If you don't want to go to the effort to learn how not to shoot yourself in the foot, you should be using a language designed to make doing so difficult. Shell is not that language.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have to exec a job with a script and later the script become garbage, it's stupid spend too much time Just to keep the purists happy

Comment: As I said above, the goal is not just theoretical purity, the goal is security and robustness against undefined behaviors in the presence of unexpected data (whether that data is accidental or malicious).

Comment: I found a solution, may be not the better but it works. It's enough replace $command with eval $command and all works

Comment: "Works", yes, at the risk of security vulnerabilities. Again, the links provided (particularly [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)) explain this.

Comment: In this particular case, you could just `"${name_exe}" >"${file1_name}.txt" 2>"${file2_name}.txt"` without first assigning it to a `command` variable, and you'd have something that both worked, and *also* kept the purists happy.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The data aren't extern, no security problem here.  The script pick on files the results of programs, even if there was unexpected data aren't problems here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I know that eval is evil for security rasons. However ,I repeat don't mine in this case.